# How to find the Odd and Even numbers in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Right now, I'm trying to find the odd and even numbers of an array. Here's the code of what I have so far. I know my findEvens() and findOdds() methods are messed up because they keep giving me off values whenever I try to print the final result. For example, if I try to find the odds of {1,5,8,3,10}, it gives me {5,3,0}. And if I try to find the evens of {2,5,8,7,19}, it gives me {2,8,0}. Anyone know why?

```
public class Scores {
   private int[] numbers;
   public Scores(int[] numbersIn) {
      numbers = numbersIn;
   }
   public int[] findEvens() {
      int numberEvens = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numberEvens++;
         }
      }
  int[] evens = new int[numberEvens];
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evens[count] = numbers[i];
        count++;
     }      
  }      
  return evens;
}
public int[] findOdds() {
  int numberOdds = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     if (i % 2 == 0) {
        numberOdds++;
     }
  }
  int[] odds = new int[numberOdds];
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     if (numbers[i] % 2 == 1) {
        odds[count] = numbers[i];
        count++;
     }      
  }      
  return odds;
 }
 public double calculateAverage() {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         sum += numbers[i];
      }   
      return (double) sum / numbers.length;
   }
 public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       result += numbers[i] + "\t";
    }
    return result;
 }
public String toStringInReverse() {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     result += numbers[i] + "\t";
  }
  return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: How to debug: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/debug.php

Comment: Is the order of the numbers returned from the various methods important? Ie is it acceptable to have any order? Or even be ordered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're problem is in counting how many even numbers you have

```
public int[] findEvens() {
  int numberEvens = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     if (i % 2 == 0) {
        numberEvens++;
     }
  }
```

this will always return a number that is half the size of the length of numbers because you're doing mod division on the number of elements in the array, not on the elements themselves. Add `numbers[i]` to the `if` statement

```
public int[] findEvens() {
  int numberEvens = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        numberEvens++;
     }
  }
```

looks like you've got the same problem with odd count

Comment: There's an additional problem with `Odds`: `if` expression is from `Evens`

Comment: Alright, I managed to fix both methods and changed the if statement. I think it should all work now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Accepting the right answer is good for everyone concerned.  That means clicking the little checkmark next to the answer under the up and down vote buttons

Answer (score 0):

'i' is used as conditional variable for looping. You should not divide this by 2. You have to divide the array element. like

```
      if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        numberEvens++;
     }
```

then it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddEven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number Elements in Array");
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("enter Elements ");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        int [] odd = filterOdd(arr);
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                System.out.println("Odd" + odd[i]);
            }
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
        int [] even = filterEven(arr);
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                System.out.println("Even" + even[i]);
            }
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
    }
    public static int[] filterOdd(int[] a) {
        int l = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i]%2==1) {
                l++;
            }
        }
        int k[]=new int[l];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i]%2==1) {
                k[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
    public static int[] filterEven(int[] a) {
        int l = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i]%2==0) {
                l++;
            }
        }
        int k[] = new int[l];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i]%2==0) {
                k[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Array {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Array declaration and value asign
        int number[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        // for loop to move number
        for(int p=0;p<number.length;p++)
        {
            // check number is even or odd??
            if(number[p]%2==0)

                System.out.println(number[p]+ " is Even number");
            else
                System.out.println( number[p]+" is odd umber");




        }

                }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Odd array one columns and another columns even array

```
public class OddEven {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int ss[]=new int[10];
        int odd[]=new int[10];
        int i;
        int k;

        for( i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]%2==0)
            {
               ss[i]=arr[i];
               System.out.print(""+ss[i]);
               System.out.print(" ");
            }

            if((arr[i]%2)!=0)
            {
                 odd[i]=arr[i];

                 System.out.print(""+odd[i]);
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }else
            {
                 System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

========================================output==============================
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8