# How to find even or odd in array?

Tags: java

How can I find even or odd in array?

```
        int size;
        int[] myArray = new int[10];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers do you enter:");
        size = input.nextInt();

        for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {           
            System.out.print("Enter number:");      
            myArray[c] = input.nextInt();
        }

        input.close();

        for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {           
            System.out.println(myArray[c]);     
        }

        if(size%2)
        {
            System.out.print("sadsadsad");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: `if(num % 2 == 0) { // even number } else {//odd number}`

Comment: it's duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352569/how-to-find-the-odd-and-even-numbers-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to check with the `size`?

Is that you want to check that if the length of the array is odd or even?

If you want the odd and even numbers in an array, you need to check it with each element in the for loop itself.

```
for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
 {   
    if(myarray[c]%2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.print(myarray[c] + " is even");
    }            
    else
    {
     System.out.print(myarray[c] + " is odd");    
    }
}
```

**Edit**
A better way to find even or odd is to check only the last number.

> We know that if the last digit is divisible by 2 then it is an even else it is an odd.

So If you want to check, we just check the last digit instead of using the `%` operator for the whole number.

```
 for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
     {   
        if(isEven(myarray[c]))
        {
            System.out.print(myarray[c] + " is even");
        }            
        else
        {
         System.out.print(myarray[c] + " is odd");    
        }
    }

public boolean isEven(int number)
{
 return (number%10) % 2 == 0;//number % 10 gets the last digit, checks if it is divisible by 2 or not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether a number is even or odd

```
if((x%2)==0)
   // even
else
   // odd
```

or

You can use the modulus operator, but that can be slow. If it's an integer, you can do:

```
if ( (x & 1) == 0 ) { even... } else { odd... }
```

here is your edited code

```
for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {           
            if(myArray[c]%2==0)//check num is even or odd
            System.out.println(myArray[c]+" even");   
            else
            System.out.println(myArray[c]+" even");  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus operator to check if the number is even or odd. If we divide any number by 2 and reminder is 0 then the number is **even**, otherwise it is **odd**.

```
  for(int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){

      if(numbers[i]%2 == 0)
          System.out.println(numbers[i] + " is even number.");
      else
          System.out.println(numbers[i] + " is odd number.");

  }
```